# How can I write a unit test for an angular 6 service's function that has a nested function in jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, amazon-cognito

I have a method in my service that is dealing with aws-congnito services internally. I am stuck here. I am unable to write the expectation of this function.

Here is what I have:

```
  getCurrentUserSession() {
    this.cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
    if (this.cognitoUser === null) {
      return false;
    }
    this.cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {
      if (err) {
        return false;
      }
      console.log('session validity: ' + session.isValid());
      return session.isValid();
    });
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to test? Each unit test should be focusing on a single class/method. All else can be stubbed out. So, please specify what unit you are testing.

Comment: ` getCurrentUserSession ` is a method of a ` class `. i want to write unit test for this method. what is the right approach?

Comment: If you want an answer, post the relevant code. We have no idea what `userPool` is. It should probably be `this.userPool`, and this instance field should be a service, that you should mock.